# Themeforest template ruby on rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, themes

I am trying to use this [theme](http://themeforest.net/item/flat-dream-responsive-admin-template/6621238?WT.ac=portfolio_item&WT.seg_1=portfolio_item&WT.z_author=CondorThemes) in my existing Rails application. And it's becoming hell.

I separated a basic HTML of the dashboard, with the minimum libraries necessary to make the theme show up properly. The result is that I need at least:

1. jQuery ( I've got it via gem, but I tried copy-pasting it to the assets folder too)
2. jquery.jpushmenu.
3. jquery.nanoscroller
4. jquery.ui
5. bootstrap.min.js **and** bootstrap.css ( same cas as jQuery)
6. some script wrote by the author `core.js`

I copied them all to the `stylesheet/javascript` folders respectively. But the UI just doesn't show up. Although all the JS/CSS are loaded properly.

Any other experiences, recommendations?

Comment: I've already imported themes following this steps: 
1. Remove the assets generated by rails
2. Copy the .css files to assets/stylesheets
3. Copy the .js file to assets/javascripts
4. Copy images to assets/images
5. Install jquery via gem
6. Eventually fix some img paths...

Check out this gem: https://github.com/drnic/install_theme

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I was also following those guidelines in order to make this work, but no luck. After a lot of time messing with this though, I noticed that the `index.html` page has a `<body class="animated">`. Upon removal of that class in the `body` tag, the dashboard all of a sudden appears. I guess the lack of some JS file(which I havent located yet), didn't let it show up. Also I appreciate the link to the `install_theme` gem, I also found it but thought that was a bit too outdated so I didnt give it a try. Did it work for you using Rails 3.2+ ?